# Why this map method repeats itself twice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object

So there are this challenge in [freecodecamp](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/functional-programming/use-the-map-method-to-extract-data-from-an-array)

This is my code:

```
var rating = [];
watchList.map(movie => {
    rating.push({  
      title: movie["title"], 
      rating: movie["imdbRating"]
    })
});
```

The problem that I noticed in console is that the map method repeats 2 twice, why? Shouldn't `.map()` stop when it passes all array items?

Comment: No it does not repeat twice? And `var rating = watchList.map(movie => ({ title: movie.title, rating: movie.mdbRatig }));` is way more concise.

Comment: Nothing shown would indicate why. Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue

Comment: I swear that it was repeating itself in Firefox console minutes ago, I must have edited the code. However, the problem now that it returns title undefined, why? Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need somth like this ?

```
var watchList = [{title: 'title1', imdbRating: '2'}, {title: 'title12', imdbRating: '3'}, {title: 'title12', imdbRating: '3', name: 'name'}]
var rating = [];

watchList.map(movie => ({
        title: movie["title"], rating: movie["imdbRating"] 
}));
```

result:

```
[{title: "title1", rating: "2"}, {title: "title12", rating: "3"}, {title: "title12", rating: "3"}]
```

Comment: OP has already answered his own question as it was a typo. But the bigger issue here is that your map isn't going to do anything worthwhile if you don't assign the results to a variable...ie `var rating = watchList.map(...`

Comment: It's ok. I already solved it. Also, your code doesn't work as your map doesn't push anything to the variable "rating"

Comment: @TechnoKnight I don't know if you just don't know the terminology for how `map` puts information into the array it creates, but just know that in `map` you don't use push in the sense of `myArray.push()`. You `return` a value as it's iterating the array. Think of the `return xxx` as your `push(xxx)`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I forgot that Javascript is case-sensitive so I had to write title in map method with a big t instead of little one.

Thanks for the help btw. I solved it!